# Unit Test for virtual Properties

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection

Because of Lazy-Loading in NHibernate I have to ensure that every Property of my Domain is virtual. 
I would like to do this by writing a Unit Test checking per reflection that all the public properties of all classes in a specific namespace are virtual.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance Tobi

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to use reflection to get all domain classes and properties in it?

Comment: @WouterdeKort in fact I have no idea right now. I played around with reflection but not in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've adapted a piece of code from a similar case I have, this should get you going;

```
    public static bool Test<T>()
    {
        var valid = true;

        foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            var accessor = property.GetAccessors()[0];
            if (accessor.IsVirtual)
                continue;

            Console.WriteLine("Member " + typeof(T).Name + "." + property.Name + " is not virtual");
            valid = false;
        }

        return valid;
    }
```

you'd use this in this way:

```
var valid = Test<User>();
```

Comment: why? the this is done for you when you build the session factory. the application won't (shouldn't) start if the session factory cannot be created. if you really want a test, just build the session factory against an in-memory sqlite database. if no exceptions are thrown all entities have virtual members.

Answer (score 3):

no need, just build the session factory. if properties aren't virtual configuration will throw a detailed message telling you what's wrong.

Comment: it's the core of NH. it's how you open a session. you have the configuration, the session factory and sessions. configuration build session factory (singleton), factory creates sessions (transient)